# Running a function in Wordpress when publishing a custom post type

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to run the following function anytime a wordpress "Jobs" custom post is published. The code works (lines 2-7) when it is placed in my theme template, but it only runs when the post is viewed. I want the code to run when the post is published, and so I have tried adding the code in a function inside my functions.php, but nothing is happening when each custom post is published. Any suggestions?

```
function indeedgeo(){
    $indeedgeo = get_post_meta($post>ID, indeedgeo, true);
    $indeedgeos=explode(' ',$indeedgeo);
    $_jr_geo_latitude = $indeedgeos[0];
    $_jr_geo_longitude = $indeedgeos[1];
    update_post_meta($post->ID, _jr_geo_latitude, $_jr_geo_latitude);
    update_post_meta($post->ID, _jr_geo_longitude, $_jr_geo_longitude);
    }
add_action('publish_Jobs', 'indeedgeo');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should hook into one of the three actions;

```
do_action('edit_post', $post_id, $post);
do_action('save_post', $post_id, $post);
do_action('wp_insert_post', $post_id, $post);
```

that are run when a post is either saved, or has its status updated. Something like the following should do the trick.

```
function se_10441543_save_post($post_id, $post){
    //determine post type
    if(get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'your_post_type'){
        //run your code
        $indeedgeo = get_post_meta($post_id, indeedgeo, true);
        $indeedgeos=explode(' ',$indeedgeo);
        $_jr_geo_latitude = $indeedgeos[0];
        $_jr_geo_longitude = $indeedgeos[1];
        update_post_meta($post_id, _jr_geo_latitude, $_jr_geo_latitude);
        update_post_meta($post_id, _jr_geo_longitude, $_jr_geo_longitude);
    }
}

add_action('save_post', 'se_10441543_save_post', 10, 2);
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Comment: This makes sense but doesn't do anything when the custom post is published/updated. The code has been added to functions.php and the only thing that I changed was to input the custom post type name. The //run your code section works fine when inserted into my theme template.

Comment: if you add in a wp_die(print_r($post)); before the if test for your posttype, what does it say when you then try to publish your post? That will at least indicate that the action is getting called.

Comment: Thanks for your response. With the line added I get the following when trying to bulk import posts from a rss feed (as is the usual method): 
`stdClass Object ( [ID] => 3952 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2012-05-04 17:35:43 [post_date_gmt] => 2012-05-04 17:35:43 [post_content] =>`

Comment: If I try to add a custom post manually I get the following:
`stdClass Object ( [ID] => 3953 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2012-05-04 21:33:54 [post_date_gmt] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 [post_content] => [post_title] => Auto Draft [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => auto-draft [comment_status] => open [ping_status] => open [post_password] => [post_name] => [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2012-05-04 21:33:54 [post_modified_gmt] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0 [guid] => [menu_order] => 0 [post_type] => job_listing [[[Cut off due to comment length]]]

Comment: here's the rest: `[post_type] => job_listing [post_mime_type] => [comment_count] => 0 [ancestors] => Array ( ) [filter] => raw ) 1` I'm guessing this is showing all the functions that are running? I don't see my function there so it appears it's not running?

Comment: Ok so the issue is with the save_post/edit_post/wp_insert_post. When I use edit_post and I manually edit a post, the function works. So the issue must be that the method I am importing posts with (Autoblogged plugin which imports posts from RSS feeds) bypasses these actions.

Comment: I think the plugin is importing posts using the `xmlrpc_methods` hook

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I am moving this to a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457257/wordpress-function-not-running-when-importing-posts-via-rss

Comment: Ahh OK, if you are not using the standard post insertion methods, then I guess those actions wont run.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure how your "publish_jobs" hook is working but right off the bat, if you are placing this function in your functions.php, you will need to give it context. Replace `$post>ID` with the post number (an integer). If this applies to many post you will probably want to use another method of querying post data: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: publish_jobs hook info taken from http://www.wpmods.com/custom-post-type-publish-action-hook/